# Playback state of MPMusicPlayer giving wrong state

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app just works like Default iPod player in iPhone.

-> It will get all Playlists , artists, albums and songs from iPod music player. 
-> It works fine in  less than ios 5.0, But when comes to 5.0 or more i am getting wrong playback states (some times). Please help me.

-> This is my code when i select song from songlists, mediaItemCollection contains songslist and indexofcurrentObject is song number

```
- (void)updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection currentIndex:(int)indexOfCurrentObject
```

{

```
[musicPlayer stop];
if (userMediaItemCollection)
{
userMediaItemCollection=nil; 
}
musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem=nil;

userMediaItemCollection=[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[mediaItemCollection items]];

[musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:userMediaItemCollection];
[musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:[[userMediaItemCollection items]objectAtIndex:indexOfCurrentObject]];
[self enablePrevAndNextButtons];

[musicPlayer play];
```

}

```
-(void)playbackStateDidChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
```

{

```
if (musicPlayer.playbackState!=MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
{
    [playPauseButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if(musicPlayer.playbackState==MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
{
    [playPauseButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause_iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

}

Comment: Do we get any clues? Do you want to add your code or the wrong status you get etc?

Comment: MPMusicPlaybackState has more than 2 states, you are not catering for all of them in your code

Comment: s, i know pause, stop and playing states. while playing also i am getting pause state, here is my code: [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState]

Comment: @ sankar siva. i am having exactly the same issue.please can anybody help me ? any suggetion ?